# PlaylistLoader() not found in NAudio c#

Tags: c#, wpf, naudio

```
    private void LoadPlaylist(object p)
    {
        var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "PLAYLIST files (*.playlist) | *.playlist";
        string abc = ofd.ShowDialog().ToString();
        if (abc == "OK")
        {
            Playlist = new PlaylistLoader().Load(ofd.FileName).ToObservableCollection(); // load the playlist 
        }
    }
```

I try to implement an Audio Player using NAudio. I use the reference https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/microsoft-net/building-a-wpf-media-player-using-naudio
But "PlaylistLoader" class was not found. "Playlist" is an ObservableCollection of type "Track". I try to add audio file to Track object as hadcoded, but failed. Anyone familiar with NAudio please help.

Answer (score 0):

`PlaylistLoader` is not part of NAudio. It is a helper class created by the author of that article, so you should download the source if available or ask the author to provide code

Comment: Thanks, I made it by myself.